# how to simplify nested pipes/ arg reference in javascript fp?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have to expose the argument passed to "getOrNewThing" (config), so when I fold the task I can use it again at "AddThenGetThing".

here is where it started:

```
export const getOrNewThing= ctx => cfg => pipe(
  GetThingByName(ctx),
  T.fold(()=>AddThenGetThing(ctx)(cfg),T.of),
)(cfg);
```

got then improved to:

```
export const getOrNewThing= ctx => cfg =>
  GetThingByName(ctx)(cfg)
    .fold(()=>AddThenGetThing(ctx)(cfg),T.of);
```

signatures:

//* GetThingByName:: (Ctx -> Object) => Task(Promise(Thing))

//* AddThenGetThing:: (Ctx -> Object) => Task(Promise(Thing))

All works but I feel I am missing something here.
Can this be simplified to be more point free but still as readable?

Thanks

Comment: What's the difference between `->` and `=>`? Also these signatures don't seem to match the curried functions that you're using.

Comment: Looks like you want to lift `getOrNewThing = GetThingByName.fold(AddThenGetThing, T.of);` into a reader monad that makes `ctx` and `cfg` available

Comment: I see now why to use the reader. But seems to me it kinda falls into the same field. I think manually currying the function and explicitly referencing the cfg it easier to grasp and has no purpose to inject at run time as I know the values before hand.

Would you know the downside of what I am doing and why would be better to use the reader instead?

As for the types the fat arrow does not mean anything special both functions expect a ctx, then a object as cfg and give a Task of a promise holding the value.